# How I can get a specific custom option field in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a specific field added in DB for custom options. I follow this thread to add it - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/73036/P15/

Instead of weight I use two other fields which I want to pass to a shipping company when an order is placed. I have module which doing this and in the observer i have this code:

```
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();

foreach ($orderItems as $item) {

$optionsArr = $item->getProductOptions();

foreach ($optionsArr['options'] as $option) {
  if($option['label'] !='' && $option['value'] !='') {

    $optionValue = $option['value']; // OK
    $optionId = $option['option_id']; // OK
    $optionWeight = $option['weight']; // NOT WORKING
    $optionMyCustomField = $option['my_custom_field']; // NOT WORKING

  }
}
}
```

This way I can get selected option value and ID.

How I can get my custom fields from the DB?

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
$optionWeight = $option['weight']; // NOT WORKING
$optionMyCustomField = $option['my_custom_field']; // NOT WORKING
```

with:

```
$optionWeight = $item->getWeight();
$optionMyCustomField = $item->getMyCustomField();
```

You can take them out of your foreach loop too.

Comment: it doesn't make much sense since I need to get a field of the selected option row (catalog_product_option_type_value table) - weight of the selected option but not of the product. see the code above - i added more of it